# np.quantile running very slowly on 3d arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cpu-cores

I am trying to compute the .95 quantile over the 3rd dimension of 3D NumPy array using NumPy's quantile function. I am finding that this is taking an extremely long time to compute and is creating a major bottleneck in my analysis. The following code appears to reproduce the lengthy computation I am experiencing:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.normal(1, 3, size=(2000, 2000,200))

quants_95 = np.quantile(arr, q = .95, axis = 2)
```

Perhaps one of the reasons this seems so much slower than the rest of my analysis is that np.quantile appears to be running on a single core whereas other numpy functions (such as np.correff) run on multiple cores as default. Does anyone know of a way to run np.quantile on multiple cores, or a similar function that does?

Comment: You could either write it yourself with `multiprocessing` or attempt to use `numba`.

Comment: I don't think there's anything going on other than your data being too big and possible running into memory issues, not necessarily cpu issues